# How do I format the date in html-export with Org-mode?

Tags: datetime, org-mode

I recently upgraded org-mode from 7.8 to 7.9 and the output of "%d" in the html postamble changed from the semi-reasonable "2012-09-11 11:35:11 PDT" to the ISO8601 format "2012-11-08T10:34-0800".  Is it possible to customize this to just display the date and no time for instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.  One can customize the variable

```
org-export-html-date-format-string
```

to get any desired format.